# Struggling with backslashes in subprocess.run

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get to grips with backslashes in Windows paths of subprocess.run. I've read that the output escapes the backslashes and it;s nothing to worry about. But, it looks like the backslashes are actually being passed to subprocess.run. I've tried all 8 permutation of single v escaped backslash, uing r v no r and single v double quotes, but none seem to work.

I am using shell=True because the documentation says I should when using command built into the shell.

Does anyone know what the correct incantation is please?
Thanks in advance.

Here are my attempts:

```
1.
subprocess.run(['dir C:\'], shell=True)

doesn't allow this

2.
subprocess.run(['dir C:\\'], shell=True)
'"dir C:\\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
CompletedProcess(args=['dir C:\\'], returncode=1)

3. 
subprocess.run([r'dir C:\'], shell=True)

doesn't allow this

4.
subprocess.run([r'dir C:\\'], shell=True)
'"dir C:\\\\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
CompletedProcess(args=['dir C:\\\\'], returncode=1)

5. 
subprocess.run(["dir C:\"], shell=True)

doesn't allow this

6.
subprocess.run(["dir C:\\"], shell=True)
'"dir C:\\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
CompletedProcess(args=['dir C:\\'], returncode=1)

7.
subprocess.run([r"dir C:\"], shell=True)

doesn't allow this

8.
subprocess.run([r"dir C:\\"], shell=True)
'"dir C:\\\\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
CompletedProcess(args=['dir C:\\\\'], returncode=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('dir "C:/"', shell=True)
```

It seems windows does not like it (even in CMD) when you surround the path with single quotes. It does like it when you give it double-quotes. So use single quotes to signify string and double-quotes to surround the actual path. Furthermore, python (and Windows) don't mind if you use forward-slashes instead of backward-slashes in paths.
And yes, in this case you do need shell=True. Just try to stay away from it when you can!

Comment: Thanks alex_bits - that was spot on. That was one permutation I didn't try. :-) Works a treat - marked as the answer. All the best!